# Why do I get a 405 Error in ASP.NET when posting back to "/"?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

Whenever I do a postback to "/", I get a 405 error.  However, when I post back to "Default.aspx", things work fine.

As I am somewhat new to web devleopment, I haven't the foggiest idea on how to debug this.  The issue driving me particularly nuts because I'm testing submitting a form on the front page of the site I'm working on.

Some environmental info:
- IIS 5.1 on Windows XP
- We use ISAPI Rewrite to route our URLs.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest a read of this blog post ["Url Rewriting with ASP.NET"](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) from Scott Guthrie.

The bit near the bottom entitled **"Handling ASP.NET PostBacks with URL Rewriting"** is particularly helpful - the [ASP.NET 2.0 Control Adapter](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/29/tip-trick-use-the-asp-net-2-0-css-control-adapters-for-css-friendly-html-output.aspx) was the key for us.

Answer (score 2):

> IIS 5.1 only allows HTTP requests of type to GET to unmapped files. HTTP requests of type POST, HEAD, and all others are responded to with a 405 resource not allowed error.

More information:

http://www.somacon.com/p126.php